# Pylanetary Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax when using spex files

Tags: python, syntax

I've been working with this code for about a year now and are just know receiving this syntax error at the beginning of my code:

```
 File "/projects/opag/kjwhite/playground_ed/2023jun24/example/submitjob_spex_singlejob.sh", line 11
    export PATH= /projects/opag/bin_2023oct24:${PATH}
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what is causing the new issue

I tried to make sure it wasn't any tab or spacing issue and even quit the terminal and restarted it only to get the same error. Does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a bash script using a python interpreter, which obviously isn't going to work because bash isn't python.

Comment: You are trying to execute a shell script `submitjob_spex_singlejob.sh` like it was a Python script. Don't do that.

Comment: @CoryKramer so how would I run it?